# Sending packets through a virtual interface whose subnet is also same as subnet of another interface

Tags: networking

I have a Linux machine with two interfaces eth0 and eth1.
eth0 has 192.168.2.30 and eth1 has 172.16.30.20. eth0 is connected to a router which is the gateway too for the WAN. eth1 is connected to LAN. All is working well until I had to connect a 
 set of devices with IP rage 192.168.2.5 - 192.168.2.15 to the LAN to which eth1 is also connected.

I want to send a multicast packet to these devices. Since the multicast works on the same subnet, I created an IP alias using following.

system("ifconfig eth1:1 192.168.2.100 netmask 255.255.255.0 up");

Despite adding the above, the packets are not going through eth1. This is found to be because eth0 is also having the same subnet as that of eth1: 1.

I tried calling ip route add <multicast ip> dev eth1. But, no success.

Appreciate if anyone could offer suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it you have at least two problems here and depending on the solution you choose other issues may arise.

Problem one, Overlapping subnets: The absolute 100% correct way to resolve this is to change the subnets so they don't overlap. I can't stress enough how important this is in your situation. If these computer on 192.168.2.5 - 192.168.2.15 are suppose to be connected to the same network as eth0 then you need to reconsider your setup as this would never work because you will create a networking loop or bad routes.

In the first situation where 192.168.2.5 - 192.168.2.15 and 192.168.2.15 aren't physically connected in any way and if someone above you says you can't do this you can try creating a NAT on eth1 so that your system sees the subnet on a different network. But this can make understanding the routes confusing and may interfere with multicast traffic.

After this is done run a tracerroute to ensure traffic is passing correctly. If not please provide the output and the route you expect it to take along with the current setup.

If multicasting doesn't work still then I recommend to create another question for it.